# Divide an array into subarrays as equally as possible for core-mapping

Tags: arrays, image-processing, multiprocessing

What algorithms are used to map an image array to multiple cores for processing? I've been trying to come up with something that will return a list of (disjoint) ranges over which to iterate in an array, and so far I have the following.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np


def divider(arr_dims, coreNum=1):
    """ Get a bunch of iterable ranges; 
    Example input: [[[0, 24], [15, 25]]]
    """
    if (coreNum == 1):
        return arr_dims

    elif (coreNum < 1):
        raise ValueError(\
      'partitioner expected a positive number of cores, got %d'\
                    % coreNum
        )

    elif (coreNum % 2):
        raise ValueError(\
      'partitioner expected an even number of cores, got %d'\
                    % coreNum
        )

    total = []

    # Split each coordinate in arr_dims in _half_
    for arr_dim in arr_dims:
        dY = arr_dim[0][1] - arr_dim[0][0]
        dX = arr_dim[1][1] - arr_dim[1][0]

        if ((coreNum,)*2 > (dY, dX)):
            coreNum = max(dY, dX)
            coreNum -= 1 if (coreNum % 2 and coreNum > 1) else 0

        new_c1, new_c2, = [], []

        if (dY >= dX):
            # Subimage height is greater than its width
            half = dY // 2
            new_c1.append([arr_dim[0][0], arr_dim[0][0] + half])
            new_c1.append(arr_dim[1])

            new_c2.append([arr_dim[0][0] + half, arr_dim[0][1]])
            new_c2.append(arr_dim[1])

        else:
            # Subimage width is greater than its height
            half = dX // 2
            new_c1.append(arr_dim[0])
            new_c1.append([arr_dim[1][0], half])

            new_c2.append(arr_dim[0])
            new_c2.append([arr_dim[1][0] + half, arr_dim[1][1]])

        total.append(new_c1), total.append(new_c2)

    # If the number of cores is 1, we get back the total; Else,
    # we split each in total, etc.; it's turtles all the way down
    return divider(total, coreNum // 2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import numpy as np
    X = np.random.randn(25 - 1, 36 - 1)
    dims = [zip([0, 0], list(X.shape))]
    dims = [list(j) for i in dims for j in dims[0] if type(j) != list]
    print(divider([dims], 2))
```

It's incredibly limited, however, because it only accepts a number of cores that's some power of 2, and then I'm certain there's edge cases I'm overlooking. Running it returns `[[[0, 24], [0, 17]], [[0, 24], [17, 35]]]`, and then using `pathos` I've mapped the first set to one core in my laptop and the second to another.

I guess I just don't know how to geometrically walk my way through partitioning an image into segments that are as similar in *size* as possible, so that each core on a given machine has the same amount of work to do.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you try to do here (I'm not familiar with graphical processing), but python's multiprocessing has a concept of a `Pool` which has a number of workers and you can send each worker a batch of e.g. 100 datapoints which he processes and returns and then waits for the next batch. This way you don't need to split up the jobs evenly into the number of available cores but you can just send them out in chunks. Would that solve your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not too sure what you're trying to achieve, but if you want to split an array (of whatever dimensions) into multiple parts you can look into the numpy.array_split method [numpy.array_split](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html).

It partitions an array into an almost equal number of parts, so it works even when the number of partitions cannot cleanly divide the array.